# Mongoose/MongoDB sum up fields of an array for subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am rather new to MongoDB/Mongoose and I have no idea how I am supposed to get the result I am looking for. Basically I have a document like this:

```
{
    "playerId" : "",
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "start" : "",
            "end" : "",
            "join" : "",
            "leave" : "",
            "rounds" : [,
                {
                    "name" : "roundName",
                    "weapons" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name" : "roundName",
                    "weapons" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name" : "roundName",
                    "weapons" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "weaponName",
                            "kills" : 1,
                            "assits" : 1,
                            "deaths" : 1,
                            "shots" : 1,
                            "headshots" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is a query that adds fields to each round (kills, deaths, assists, headshots, shots) which contain the sum of all their weapons. The same should happen for the entire session if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include an example document from your collection instead of describing the schema. Also would be best to show your expected output from the example documents(s).

Comment: I kinda rewrote the question with exactly what I need and an example document. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the following should give you list of stats grouping by session->rounds:
the assumption here is 1) name of the collection is shootingGame 2) name of the fields are $sessions.Rounds.Weapons

```
db.shootingGame.aggregate(
   [
       {$group: {
       _id: "$sessions.Rounds", 
       "sumkills": {$sum: "$sessions.Rounds.Weapons.kills" },
       "sumasists": {$sum: "$sessions.Rounds.Weapons.assists" },
       "sumdeaths": {$sum: "$sessions.Rounds.Weapons.deaths" },
       "sumheadshots": {$sum: "$sessions.Rounds.Weapons.headshots" },
       "sumshots": {$sum: "$sessions.Rounds.Weapons.shots" }
   }}
   ]
)
```

But for further grouping per session, you have to store this result into another document and run another $sum group per round

Comment: I tried your approach and got a value of 0 for all fields. But that may be because of my poor explanation of what my document looks like. Therefore I added an example document to my question.

Comment: Same, got value 0